# Canvas exact touch detection

Tags: android, bitmap, position, touch, android-canvas

i've got an android TicTacToe App. First, I draw the board:

```
Canvas canvas = sh.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.board);
    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, canvasWidth, canvasHeight / 2, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, canvasWidth / 2 - bm.getWidth() / 2, 0, null);
    sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

Now I want to detect, where the user touches the board (top left corner, top middle, etc.). What is the best way for doing this? I could get the coordinates of a touch, but then I had to write this code again for every device (hadn't I?), and I somehow had to define a range of coordinates (if he touches from (0,0) to (20,20) for example). Board:

[image]

I could also use a simple ImageView and put invisible Buttons over it, but then I'd had to define the layout for all devices because even when I'm using dp the distances are always a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I didn't use a Canvas at all; I just used an ImageView and put invisible Buttons over it. I had to define the layout for normal, large and xlarge and for some devices I had to define an extra layout.

Answer (score 0):

For any view, you can set up an OnTouchListener which will provide events when then user touches the screen, moves where previously touched, adds a second touch point, etc.

```
private OnTouchListener myTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : 
          // do something on move
          <snip>
```

Once you've got your app reacting to touches, you can determine where the touches landed.
I find the easiest way is to set up Rect areas on items you want to allow the user to touch.

For example, let's say you have a 'Play' button in your canvas. You can see if the user touches it by first setting up the Rect describing the bounds

```
uiPlayBtn = new RectF(uiZone.left+sizeX,uiZone.top, uiZone.left+sizeX+play_button.getWidth(),uiZone.bottom);
```

This sets the buttons' bounds to be relative to adjacent items rather than fixed XY locations.  How you determine the Rect boundaries will determine whether you do this for every device, or make it generic.  This sets the play button to be next to the left and top and the right and bottom are set to be left/top plus the width/height

Then, in your touchListener, you can check for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

```
if (uiPlayBtn.contains(downX, downY)) {  
  // do something - the user touched me
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the coordinates of the rectangle? I have one image of the board which is located in the center of the screen. How do I get the coordinates of a rectangle in the top left corner of the field?

Comment: `topLeft = new RectF((canvasWidth - bm.getWidth()) / 2,0,1/3 * bm.getWidth() + (canvasWidth - bm.getWidth()) / 2,1/3 * bm.getHeight())` - The bitmap is located in the center, so the x coordinate of the left side of the board is ((canvasWidth - bm.getWidth()) / 2 and so on. But I don't think this code is correct, I just tried it. Could I somwhow make the RectF visible?Then it would be much easier to get the correct position.